# Insert unique ID in MS Word document

Tags: ms-word, uniqueidentifier

pleas help a VBA noob.

We are writing requirements specifications in MS Word which are then tested by test cases in JIRA. I want to identify each requirement by creating a unique ID in MS Word.

Hence I am looking for a Macro which inserts e.g. a 5 digit unique id based on user input at the current position in the MS Word document.

Thanks in advance :-)
ovid**99**

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of lines to show you how to create a unique GUID you can attach to your test cases:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim GetGUID As String
    GetGUID = Mid$(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36)

    MsgBox GetGUID

End Sub
```

The example just generates the GUID and shows it in a messagebox for demo purposes.